# PHP: Show/Hide Div On Specific Pages

Tags: php

I've added the following code to pages to display a notice I only have to write once.

PHP

```
<?php require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/notice.php"; ?>
```

HTML

```
<div class="notice-1">
   <div class="date-event">2018-09-30 11:00</div> <!-- Hide notice when date/time expires -->
   <p class="notice-22-1">Daylight Saving begins Sunday 30th Sept
   </p>
</div>
```

From time to time, however, I want to display this message on particular pages, such as /contact.

Here's what I've come up with. I'm new to this, so I have no idea...

PHP

```
<?php 
    if( is_page( array( "new1", "contact1" ) ) ) {
        $showdiv = 'notice-1';
    }
?>
```

Note: I've assigned a page id (e.g. "contact1") to help make an array.

In action: https://www.citychurchchristchurch.co.nz/new

I can't get this to work. Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is `is_page`? Are you working on Wordpress?

Comment: Thank you Ali for your response. I think I've got confused with a WordPress solution (show how bad I am at this). I'm not using WordPress. Is there an alternative I could use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <?php
      //list your intended pages in an array
      $intended_pages = array('page1', 'page7', 'page12');

      //get the current page name
      $page_name= basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

      //check if the current page is on the list
      If(in_array($page_name, $intended_pages))
      { 
        //current page is on the list so perform function
        $showdiv = 'notice-1'; 
      }
 ?>
```

Comment: Thank you @Bobby. I can't seem to get this to work. Couple of questions... 1. Can this be added to the /notice.php document? 2. Are the pages identified as '/new' (by page address) or by 'new1' by page id? 3. Just to be clear, I'm not using WordPress in case my op was misleading. Not sure if you code includes anything for that. Anyway, thanks again for your help!

Comment: You can put this as a single file then `include();` this to all the pages where you require the notice to show. Then `$intended_pages` will contain in an array the names of all the pages where you wish the notice to show eg: login.php, about.php, dashbord.html etc